Django & Pycharm keep giving me URL error
I keep geeting this Login  although in my project I make zero mention of log in
Page not found (404)  
Request Method: GET  
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/  
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:  

admin/,
login/, 

didn’t match any of these.

Django settings for mysite project:
# Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.3.
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "secret code"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
July 04, 2024 - 17:36:23
Django version 4.2.13, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

indicates that everything is corrects but weather  you command line or click on the http: address you get the above error ... i've reset the ide updated os & pycharm no matter what i get the above error even tried a work around in settings LOGIN = False still got the error .... anyone know how to solve this problem

Show us the mysite/urls.py file.

allowed host should have ['localhost', '127.0.0.1'] at least.

this is mysite/urls.py.  from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]

Does every app you create with your IDE have the same issue? Have you tried to create from outside the IDE to isolate the problem?

I've created 20 plus apps this glitched started suddenly 2 days ago
